# iOS 7 Safari: prevent UI chrome appearing differently on scroll up and scroll down

Tags: iphone, user-interface, ios7

At present, when a page is scrolled on Safari iOS 7 (11A4449D) the header chrome reduces in size and clicking anywhere in the bottom 44px of the viewport brings in the footer grey bar (with the next/prev page links etc).

Conversely, scrolling back up the page keeps the footer bar in place and the header bar at the larger size. Is there any meta-tag (or similar) in place to prevent this behaviour of make it consistent on both scroll-up and scroll-down?

We could work around the issue if the browser fired some JS event when the chrome came into/out of view but it doesn't.

Comment: (Just curious) why would you want to change that? Isn't it nice that you get more available screen space for your content?

Comment: Hi David, ordinarily, sure but working on a web app that has a fixed position element that gets invoked by a button at the bottom of the screen (via JS). At present, because with the iOS7 chrome gets removed the item is still physically in that position but the bottom 44px becomes 'inert' and it isn't possible to fire the JS event from that area (it just brings the browser chrome back into view). We could work around the issue if the browser fired some event when the chrome came into/out of view but we don't think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an update to this:

We eventually worked around this issue by using `bottom: 0;` instead of `top: 100%;` in the CSS. We had wanted to use top: 100% in the first instance as it meant that items being added into that element would be rendered down (off screen) automatically.

By taking the inverse approach we just have to manually translate the area off (using JS) an equal amount as the item being added.

This results in out 'sticky' footer staying above the bottom piece of OS chrome when that appears.

Comment: Hi @Ben, I also have the exact same situation in which the bottom and top chrome bars spoil the user experience, requiring 2 taps instead of just 1. 

I am trying to understand your workaround. Your footer, are you positioning it fixed? I didn't understand why just putting bottom: 0 does not make it work. Can you clarify how you did it?

Comment: We added the following key bits to the element you want to position:

position: fixed, bottom: 0px, transform: translate3d(0, - YOUR-HEIGHT-HERE, 0);